# How to lock a shapefile in QGIS so only I can edit

Tags: qgis, shapefile, editing, lock

I am doing a project using shapefiles in QGIS. These will be sent to somebody who will view in QGIS and I want to put a lock on the data so that it can be viewed but not edited by somebody else without my consent. Can this be done

Answer (score 3):

No, you are sending them the data so they can open it in any GIS program and edit it to their heart's content.

If you want people to only be able to view your data you should consider publishing via a WMS server that only provides an image format output.

Comment: Many thanks for such a swift reply Will go down the WMS route

Answer (score 3):

You can play with the files (**all** the Shapefile files) permissions.

If the users download the files, of course they can change the permissions to whatever they want on their computer, but the solution is easy: don't bother getting the files back, just ignore they potential modifications.

If the files are on a shared drive, set yourself as the file owner and only allow other users to read the file. Provided they are regular users (not admins), they won't be able to change the permissions. The same applies if you share a folder from your computer.